# How to save section position in one page website after browser refresh with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is a one page `index.html` website. I want to fixed the position of each section even after browser refresh. How can I modify `main.js` for required JavaScript codes for this changes?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Page Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Page Description">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="home-section"> </section>
  <section class="about-section"> </section>
  <section class="gallary-section"> </section>
  <section class="project-section"> </section>
  <section class="testimonial-section"> </section>
  <section class="contact-section"> </section>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everytime user change section (scroll position?) you will save it into localStorage then after refresh see if exist an localStorage and scroll into value of that.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Some demo code will help a lot. Can you show some demo ?

Comment: [current Element in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) - [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
     const currentURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
     let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.sec')
     sections.forEach(function(item){
        window.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
            if(isScrolledIntoView(item)){
                window.history.replaceState("", item.id , `${currentURL}#${item.id}`);
            }            
        })
     })

// this is not my code, found it in stackoverflow
     function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
      .sec{
        width: 100%;
        height:400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Page Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Page Description">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0"> -->

</head>
<body>
  <section class="home-section sec" id="sec1"> section1 </section>
  <section class="about-section sec" id="sec2"> section2 </section>
  <section class="gallary-section sec" id="sec3" > section3 </section>
  <section class="project-section sec" id="sec4"> section4 </section>
  <section class="testimonial-section sec" id="sec5"> section5 </section>
  <section class="contact-section sec" id="sec6"> section6 </section>
  <!-- <script src="js/scripts.js sec" id="sec7"></script> -->

</body>
</html>
```